# When did Iron Man fake his death with a suit full of plasma?

Tags: marvel, episode-identification, iron-man

Sometime during the 80s or 90s when Iron Man's suit was red and silver, he got into a losing battle with someone in another overpowered suit.

At the end of the issue he dies.

In the next issue it is revealed that the suit was actually filled with plasma reserves and sent up on auto and Tony wasn't inside when it got shot down/exploded.

After that Tony was in a wheelchair for a while.

Which issues was this story in and can you post pictures of the covers?

Comment: The anti-grav wheelchair? https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/8/86/Anthony_Stark%27s_Anti-Grav_Wheelchair_from_Iron_Man_Vol_1_247_0001.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130916174802 or something more mundane?

Comment: I think the chair is correct but I mixed up the reason why he ended up in it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was thinking of #230 and #231, the climax of the original ["Armor Wars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armor_Wars) storyline.

[image: Iron Man #230 Cover]

[image: Iron Man #231 Cover]

And the explanation on how he survived.
[image: Iron Man #231 Content fill suit with blood plasma]

More details here

http://peerlesspower.blogspot.com/2014/02/theres-no-escape-from-firepower.html

https://peerlesspower.blogspot.com/2014/02/the-new-iron-man.html

I think maybe I confused the wheelchair with another story.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be Iron Man #281 (1992) [The Deadly Masters of Silence](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man_Vol_1_281)?

Tony uses a "thermal charge" to remotely detonate a suit while fighting an opponent.

[image]

We then pan back to him in a sort of electric wheelchair

[image]

Comment: It was definitely red and silver armour.